# How to exclude all legacy issues by date?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We have a lot of legacy code in our repositories, and now we implement SonarQube 6.4 but our legacy code causes a lot of errors and warnings, so we would like to analyze only new written/in the future modified code and exclude the old because we have no resources to amend all issues from legacy code written during last 10 years.

How can I exclude already found issues e.g. by the date they when they were found? But we don't want to exclude all old files as such, because edit them from time to time. We just want to make sure not to add new issues.

Comment: you could actually just simply search for issues and set the time period... and set them in a bulk action to "Won't fix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube promotes the idea of a ["leak paradigm"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak). In short, the idea is to continously enrich your existing code base with clean, maintainable, secure increments - which will make your code base better over time.

Fixing **all existing** issues is not advisable.

So: define a leak period in SonarQube and [change your quality gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates#QualityGates-RecommendedQualityGate) to only leak measures. SonarQube is made for exactly your use-case!

Comment: Idefined a leak period 
where can i change the quality gate to only leak measures?
I see it's set to allways, but i can not find the according setting?

Answer (score 0):

You could change all of the issues within a time frame via Bulk change:

1. filter:
   [image: filter issues]
2. bulkchange accordingly
   [image: bulkchange]

Comment: is there a posibility to setup the bulk change to medify more than 250 issues at once? because we have 20 projects with 4000 issues and more. That are a lot of clicks.

Comment: sadly i am not aware of that... but it used to be 500 :D